# Which gtag MEASUREMENT_ID to use

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads-api

I'm a back end developer, sometimes a little fronted, but not a SEO related expert at all.
Now I have to make a full website from top to bottom and I'm stuck with the Google stuff.
First I created a Google Analytics profile, I got the srcipt that I needed to hardcode to all my site.

```
    <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-MEASUREMENT_ID></script>
    <script>
      window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
      function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
      gtag('js', new Date());

      gtag('config', 'G-MEASUREMENT_ID');
    </script>
```

However, a little while later, I started to use Google Ads and it recommended to connect my Analytics page to the Ads page, so I connected them and I got another code that I needed to insert.

The code snippet is almost the same, except the two MEASUREMENT_ID, because now I got a **UA-MEASUREMENT_ID**.

So, do I have to use both snippets, or just one? If so, which MEASUREMENT_ID should I use?
Or am I screwed up something?

Thanks all the help

Answer (score 1):

The code with `UA-` (Universal Analytics) and the one with `G-` (Google Analytics 4) belong to two completely different tracking systems in Google Analytics. If until now you have used `UA-` you should continue to do so and in parallel track with the new one `G-`. So you will have two tracking codes at the same time. This is also Google's suggestion not to lose the data history in `UA-`.